# Custom Microsoft Teams App: inconsistent behaviour in client

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a first Teams app for my org with Tabs for a number of internal SPOL sites and a Power App. When I navigate through the tabs it connects through fine until I've loaded the Power App tab - navigating to any other SPOL tab then hangs and I can only get to my Power Apps tab. The same behaviour occurs whether in the client or in the browser version of Teams. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @NickA, Could you please drop a mail at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com so that we can discuss further over call

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? I don't see any mail from your end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to the created Power App loading issue.
More details about the issue is required.